# How to iterate through a C# object's properties and update the corresponding property on another object

Tags: c#, properties, iteration, automapper, deep-copy

I have to objects of the same type, one source and one destination. What I'm attempting to do is iterate through the source object properties, and if it has a value, update the corresponding property on the second. I think I have the first part:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in object1.GetType().GetProperties())
{ 
     var val = property.GetValue(object1)
     if (val != null)
     {
         --code to update object2 current prop
     }
}
```

I figure that there must be a way to directly reference the property on object2 without having to iterate through and compare each name and type. Hope so anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `SetValue`, like so:

```
prop.SetValue(object2, val);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a need of reflection here. you can simply use the [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) here and handle the case of null.

```
public class ABC
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
    public string P2 { get; set; }
}

var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<ABC, ABC>().ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, value) => value != null));
});

Mapper mapper = new Mapper(configuration);

var b1 = new ABC { P1 = null, P2 = "b1p2" };
var b2 = new ABC { P1 = "b2p1", P2 = "b2p2" };

mapper.Map(b1, b2); //It will give you b2.P1 = b2p1 and P2 = b1p2
```